# Creating a Conditional that prints even

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have a function and if statement that I need to print "even" in the console. The statement is literally, "*If num is an even number, print out "even".  Don't do anything if num is an odd number.*"

I thought it would work if I put (num) equal to Math.random. But I got undefined. I also tried setting (num) equal to a specific number and I'm still getting undefined in the console.

How do I get this to print "even"?

```js
function isEven(num) {
    let random = Math.random();
    if (num = random ){
        console.log("even");
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. But equality is not the same as odd/even.

Comment: Take a look at the [Remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) `%`. This should help you further

Comment: Even means divisible by 2. Comparing to a random number (which will have an astronomically tiny chance of ever matching anyway) won't do you any good there...

Comment: Btw the "undefined" is just the return value of your function. You aren't returning anything.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
function isEven(num) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        console.log("even");
    }
}
```

`%` gives the remainder of integer division, and so if you do `num % 2` and the result is 0 then your number is even! Otherwise, it is an odd!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you made a random variable to generate random number
you try this instead

```
function isEven(num) {
  if (num % 2 == 0) {
    console.log("even");
  }
}
```